# My code works differently in the browser than in my IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, arrow-functions

This piece of code gives me different results based on where I run it:

```
name ="Arrow function"
let me = { 
 name: "Regular function", 
 thisInArrow:() => { 
   console.log("Example of " + this.name); //no 'this' binding here 
 }, 
 thisInRegular(){ 
   console.log("Example of " + this.name); //'this' binding works here 
 } 
};
me.thisInArrow(); 
me.thisInRegular();
```

when ran in the browser gives me the result of:

```
Example of Arrow function 
Example of Regular function
```

but when I run it in VS Code i get this:

```
Example of undefined
Example of Regular function
```

Is this a matter of my version of Node being different than the browser? I didn't see anything in the release notes that would indicate arrow functions behaving differently between versions 12 and 13

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same `saved file` and you are in the proper directory ?

Comment: in node you are running in a module context, not a `window`

Comment: @DanielA.White ah so does that mean the default scopes are different?

Comment: No. The value of `this` outside of any explicitly defined function has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: @vector213 yep exactly